# Rspec and FactoryGirl with several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i'm new using the tests on rails and i have some doubts... I need to test several models, i know how to test the basics, like the validations and associations, but i'm not sure how to approach what i need to do.

I have two models, PaymentDocument, PaymentAmount (PaymentDocument has_many PaymentAmount), each model has a field called "amount", the amount in the PaymentDocument model has the sum of every PaymentAmount associated to it. so i need to apply some math operation to each PaymentAmount amount and sum them, then do the same math operation to the PaymentDocument amount and compare it to check if there are exactly equal or i lost some decimals.

Right now i have two specs file, one for the PaymentDocument and another one for the PaymentAmount, how i can test both models at the same time (to verify if the info of each model is correct) and then apply the math operation i mention before?

payment_document_spec

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe PaymentDocument, type: :model do

  describe "validations" do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:amount) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_numerality_of(:amount).is_greater_than(0) }
  end
  describe "associations" do
   it { is_expected.to belong_to(:payment_amounts) }
  end
end
```

payment_amount_spec

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe PaymentAmount, type: :model do

  describe "validations" do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:payment_document) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:amount) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_numerality_of(:amount).is_greater_than(0) }
  end

  describe "associations" do
    it { is_expected.to have_many(:payment_document) }
  end

end
```

edit:

Example

```
   PaymentDocument
   {
    id => 1,
    amount => 3540095,94
   }
   PaymentAmounts: 
     {
      id => 1,
      pd_id => 1,
      amount => 40095.00,
    }
    {
      id => 2,
      pd_id => 1,
      amount => 500000.94,
    }
    {
      id => 2,
      pd_id => 1,
      amount => 3000000.00,
    }

#The math operation is remove divide the amounts by 1000 and round them by 2

{
  id => 1,
  pd_id => 1,
  amount => 40.10,
}
{
  id => 2,
  pd_id => 1,
  amount => 500.00,
}
{
  id => 2,
  pd_id => 1,
  amount => 3000.00,
}

#The sum of all the payment amounts is 3540.10 and if i do the same operation to the amount of the payment document the result is 3540.1 but in some cases it may not be equal so that's why i want to test this.
```

Comment: How do the `amount` columns work, exactly? You need to keep them synchronised, right? So you're trying to right a test that this synchronisation works as expected?

Comment: It's hard to suggest what test to write, if you haven't shown what needs testing ;)

Comment: Your comment about "lost some decimals" is a bit concerning. Please don't store financial figures using floating-point numbers. Store everything as integers, and convert from pence/cents into pounds/dollars when you display amounts in the view.

Comment: @TomLord i added an example

Comment: check the example please @jon

Comment: @AndresFernandes I still don't understand what you're trying to **test** here... Unless there's some critical information missing from your post, the `PaymentDocument`s and `PaymentAmount`s can have **any** values... So why would it necessarily be the case that their `amount`s add up? If there's nothing enforcing this? Sure, they *might* just so happen to add up, but you can't exactly write a test to say "ifthey add up, then they add up; if they don't then they don't".

Comment: Is there something in the `PaymentAmounts` model, that updates the `amount` of the `PaymentDocument`? Is there some service object which sets all of these values? What happens if  the `PaymentDocument` gets updated? What happens if a `PaymentAmount` gets updated? There are many ways that this *could* be implemented, but how do you expect this to work? You still haven't shown us anything, so I have no idea how to "test it".

Comment: @AndresFernandes - my comment still stands. DO NOT use floating point numbers when dealing with financial data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Assume that when creating payment_amount then associated  payment_document amount automatically updated.
if this is the case you can test it by something like that.

```
describe '#payment' do
    it 'should very amount' do
      pd = Factory.create(:payment_document)
      attributes = [ { pd_id: pd.id, amount: 40095.00 },
                     { pd_id: pd.id, amount: 500000.94 },
                     { pd_id: pd.id, amount: 3000000.00 }
                   ]
      attributes.each do |attrs|
        Factory.create(:payment_amount, attrs)
      end

     total_amount = attributes.map{ |m| m[:amount]}.sum
     expect(pd.reload.amount).to eq(total_amount)
    end
  end
```

NOTE:  this is a guess as I haven't aware of your model code.